# how to show return answer from return confirm

Tags: javascript

How to show alert result from javascript `return confirm()`?

The script is like this:

```
<td width="25" align="center" title="Delete">
<?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/ticket_controller/confirm_hr_ticket/'.$row->id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete '.$row->trans_code.'?\')">'?>
<img style="vertical-align:middle;"src="<?php echo site_url() . 'images/btn_delete.gif'; ?>"></img></a></td>
```

I want to show `alert('Data deleted')` after i click yes in confirmation.

Comment: `onclick` does not handle boolean value returned by `confirm()` as you want.

Comment: Is not related to php.

Comment: *sidenote:* it is suggested to use CSS instead of HTML attribute for styling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a function called by the onclick
like

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N46hQ/)

HTML/PHP

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/ticket_controller/confirm_hr_ticket/'.$row->id.'" onclick="return myfunction(\''.$row->trans_code.'\')">'?>
```

Javascript

```
function myfunction(transcode){
  if(confirm('Are you sure to delete '+ transcode + '?'))
  {
    //Delete data
    alert('data deleted');
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* do not use `#` in `href` attribute unless you intend to do so. Replace it with `javascript:void(0)` to prevent the page jumping to the top.

Comment: sure. it was juste for example. As we can see in the example i can replace it by '.base_url().' generated by php.

Answer (score 6):

Add a simple JS function:

```
function DeleteClick(transcode)
{
    if(confirm('Are you sure to delete ' + transCode + '?'))
    {
        alert('Data deleted');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then change your call to

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/ticket_controller/confirm_hr_ticket/'.$row->id.'" onclick="return DeleteClick(\''.$row->trans_code.'\')">'?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a function in onclick as onclick="confirmclick(userid);"

Javascript function

```
function confirmclick(userid)
{
   var answer = confirm("Are you sure to delete " + userid + "?")

    if (answer){
        alert('Data deleted');
        return true;  
    }

    return false;  
}
```

Comment: the attribute is unused.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write separate function then you may use following.

```
<td width="25" align="center" title="Delete">
    <?php echo '<a href="'.base_url().'index.php/ticket_controller/confirm_hr_ticket/'.$row->id.'" onclick="if(confirm(\'Are you sure to delete '.$row->trans_code.'?\')){alert(\'Data deleted\');}">'?>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;"src="<?php echo site_url() . 'images/btn_delete.gif'; ?>"></img></a></td>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* in modern web development, it is suggested to separate JavaScript from HTML codes, but you are doing the reverse.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yes you are correct. I am giving alternate option. Its better to call function.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor it is also better to use event binding of javascript or jquery than writing onclick event attribute on html tag. $('#idToaTag').click(function(){ //Add what you are writing in confirmclick function });